# Why does AddAfterSelf return 'JProperty cannot have multiple values' when used with SelectToken?

Tags: c#, json.net

I want to add a new JProperty to a JSON object using a string path.
I'm retrieving an existing path and then adding a new value proximal to it.
It seems no matter how I select a token, or no matter what Add method I call (most relevant is AddAfterSelf) or what I supply as a new value, I receive the exception:

> Run-time exception (line 9): Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JProperty cannot have multiple values.

You can see this failing here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/mnvmOI

Why can't I add a JProperty in this situation?

```
using System;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        JObject test = JObject.Parse("{\"test\":123,\"deeper\":{\"another\":\"value\"}}");
        test.SelectToken("deeper.another").AddAfterSelf(new JProperty("new name","new value"));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The reason that the exception is thrown is that [`SelectToken()`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/QueryJsonSelectToken.htm) returns the **property's `JValue`** not the **`JProperty` itself**.  Specifically, it returns a `JValue` owned by the `JProperty` with name `"another"`.  You can see this if you do:

```
Console.WriteLine("Result type: {0}; result parent type: {1}", result.GetType(), result.Parent.GetType());
```

Which results in

```
Result type: Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JValue; result parent type: Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JProperty
```

And if you further print the object types from the top of the `JToken` hierarchy to the value returned by `SelectToken()`, you will see the `JValue` tokens contained inside the `JProperty` tokens:

```
Depth: 0, Type: JObject
Depth: 1, Type: JProperty: deeper
Depth: 2, Type: JObject
Depth: 3, Type: JProperty: another
Depth: 4, Type: JValue: value
```

The [Json.NET documentation](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/QueryJsonSelectToken.htm) also indicates that `SelectToken()` returns the selected property's value:

> ```
> string name = (string)o.SelectToken("Manufacturers[0].Name");
>
> Console.WriteLine(name);
> // Acme Co
> ```

Since a `JProperty` cannot have more than one value, when you try to add a `JProperty` immediately after the value in the hierarchy, you are trying to add it as a child of its parent `JProperty`, which throws the exception.

Instead, add it to parent's parent:

```
test.SelectToken("deeper.another").Parent.AddAfterSelf(new JProperty("new name","new value"));
```

Sample [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/WSe5hw) showing all of the above.

Comment: Very replete answer, thank you.  I need to be more careful in checking the specific types being returned, rather than relying on the generic type of JToken.  One wonders whether 'SelectToken' may be better named though if its ultimately likely to return a primitive type value.