# Json.Net - Immediate parent path not being returned

Tags: path, json.net, parent, jsonpath

I am attempting to retrieve the path of the immediate parent of a JToken object found via SelectToken.

- grandparent

  - parent

    - object

In above structure the value of **object.Path** is "grandparent.parent.object"  and the value of **object.Parent.Path** is also "grandparent.parent.object".

Is this a bug or should the path of a parent be retrieved in another way?

Below is an example that illustrates object.Path and object.Parent.Path being the same:

```
var input = "{'grandparent': { 'parent' : {'object' : 'value'}}}";

var jsonInput = JObject.Parse(input);
var jsonObject = jsonInput.SelectToken("..object");

var path = jsonObject.Path; //grandparent.parent.object
var parentPath = jsonObject.Parent.Path; //grandparent.parent.object (same as object)
var realParentPath = jsonObject.Parent.Parent.Path; //grandparent.parent (actual parent path)
```

Comment: Can you share a [mcve]?  Possibly the immediate parent is just a `JProperty` which you're not really thinking of as a full member of the structure.

Comment: Thanks, I've added an example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have stumbled on an implementation detail of Json.NET, which is that it models a JSON object with two levels of container, namely the [`JObject`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JObject.htm) which contains a [collection](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JObject_Properties.htm) of [`JProperty`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JProperty.htm) items, each of which in turn contains the actual property [value](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JProperty_Value.htm):

```
JObject                // A JSON object: an unordered set of name/value pairs
 -> IEnumerable<JProperty> Properties()
    JProperty          // A property name/value pair
     -> string Name    // The property name
     -> JToken Value   // The property value
```

I.e., using the diagram for an *object* from https://json.org/:

[image: JSON object]

The `JObject` corresponds to the entire section between braces, and the `JProperty` corresponds to a specific `string : value` portion.

I reckon this implementation was chosen to separate the name from the value, so that [`JValue`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JValue.htm) could be used for both array and object primitive values, without having to add in a meaningless `Name` property for array items.  However, from the point of view of [`SelectToken`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SelectToken.htm), the existence of `JProperty` is a bit awkward because it doesn't correspond to anything selectable via a [JSONPath](https://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/) query since `SelectToken` always returns the actual value rather than the container property.  Newtonsoft chose to make `JProperty.Path` the same as it's value's path; possibly they could have chosen to make `JProperty.Path` throw an exception instead, but they did not.

To hide this implementation detail, you could introduce an extension method `SelectableParent()`:

```
public static partial class JsonExtensions
{
    public static JToken SelectableParent(this JToken token)
    {
        if (token == null)
            return null;
        var parent = token.Parent;
        if (parent is JProperty)
            parent = parent.Parent;
        return parent;
    }
}
```

Then use it as follows:

```
var path = jsonObject.Path; //grandparent.parent.object
var parentPath = jsonObject.SelectableParent().Path; //grandparent.parent
```

Demo fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/pHtAZU).

Related: *[Why does AddAfterSelf return 'JProperty cannot have multiple values' when used with SelectToken?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47747906/3744182)*.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation and suggested workaround, that does make a lot of sense.

Answer (score 1):

The following practical example helped my understanding of the differences between JValue and it's JProperty parent.

```
var input = "{'grandparent': { 'parent' : {'object' : 'value', 'object2': 'value2'}}}";
var jsonInput = JObject.Parse(input);

var jsonObject = jsonInput.SelectToken("..object");
//value

var jsonParentObject = jsonObject.Parent;
//"object": "value"

var jsonParentParentObject = jsonObject.Parent.Parent;
//{
//"object": "value",
//"object2": "value2"
//}

var jsonParentParentParentObject = jsonObject.Parent.Parent.Parent;
//"parent": {
//  "object": "value",
//  "object2": "value2"
//}
```